# Why exec-maven-plugin fails while java console command works?

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface, chromium-embedded

This problem has arisen while working with the Java Chromium Embedded Framework (JCEF).

The JCEF uses a native `SO` library (`libcef.so`) and a `SO` library for the JNI bindings (`libjcef.so`). I believe the embedded Chromium looks for a file named `icudtl.dat` next to it, i.e. in the same directory that the libraries reside.

For the following explanation, asume that all those required files are in the same directory, named `jcef_libs`.

I wrote a test application using JCEF. After compiling, if I execute it with the java command, i.e.

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/jcef_libs 
$ java -cp src/main/java:/path/to/maven/repo/jcef.jar:/path/to/maven/repo/jogl-all/2.2.4/*:/path/to/maven/repo/gluegen-rt/2.2.4/* tests.simple.MainFrame
```

**it works flawlessly**.

On the other hand, using the `exec-maven-plugin` raises a fatal error, due to not finding the named `icudtl.dat` file. The `POM` file is configured to use **exactly the same artifacts** as the java command does.

```
$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="tests.simple.MainFrame"
[1201/123038:FATAL:content_main_runner.cc(721)] Check failed: base::i18n::InitializeICU().
```

I have tested the java command with the `icudtl.dat` file removed from the `jcef_libs` directory, experiencing the same error, i.e. the error raises only when the `icudtl.dat` is not found.

Any help will be appreciated.

### UPDATE

I have been tracing what maven does under the hood. The failing `mvn` command above executes this internally:

```
java -classpath /usr/share/maven2/boot/classworlds.jar -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/share/maven2/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/usr/share/maven2 org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher "exec:java" "-Dexec.mainClass=tests.simple.MainFrame"
```

I.e. it executes my test application through a launcher. I don't know where this launcher is going to execute my application but, again, I need the `icudtl.dat` in that directory.

Any idea how could I workaround this?

Comment: You can't use JOGL without GlueGen and JOGL 2.2.4 is obsolete, please switch to JOGL 2.3.2. We only maintain the very latest version.

Comment: @gouessej Thank you for your comment. GlueGen is there, check the sample code, **it works** with the java command. I have changed my `POM` to use 2.3.2 but it won't fix my problem.

Comment: You comment /path/to/maven/repo/gluegen-rt in your command. You probably don't use JOGL at all.

Comment: @gouessej It is a path wildcard, not a comment. I suppose  theway the code snippet looks is confusing you... Again, the JCEF **works** when executed with the java command. No way the JOGL is not being used, I have chrome embedded in my test application and I can browse the Internet with it.